# git-filter-repo removing the folder I want to filter

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I am trying to port over a subdirectory from BitBucket to GitLab but want to keep the history. I am following the guide here to do this: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository.

The problem is that some of the commands I try are giving me error messages, and when I do get it to run it ends up deleting the subdirectory that I wanted it to filter.

I want the eid/bdd/mid_bdd directory to be the new root and keep only the history of that subdirectory.

If I try this

```
python C:/Users/USER/Downloads/git-filter-repo.txt --subdirectory-filter C:/Users/USER/git/eid/bdd/mid_bdd/
```

I get this error

```
Error: --path-rename expects one colon in its argument: <old_name:new_name>.
```

If I do this from within the eid directory

```
python C:/Users/USER/Downloads/git-filter-repo.txt --path C:/Users/USER/git/eid/bdd/mid_bdd/ --path-rename mid-bdd/: --force
```

I get this output

```
Parsed 720 commitsEnumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0

New history written in 1.01 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
Completely finished after 2.47 seconds.
```

However, my eid directory is now missing the mid_bdd folder as well as all the others.

Comment: For `--path-rename`, if you're in `eid/`, shouldn't the command be `--path-rename bdd/mid_bdd/:` ?

Comment: @TTT I tried that and all the other folders are still present

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it work by moving the git-filter-repo script into my eid directory and also installing python from the microsoft store instead of from the internet.